# GeoServer 2.9.2 does not update Bounding Box after layer shapefile is generated second time

Tags: geoserver

**ImageMosaic** store was created for raster layer. Everything OK.

Now additional **.sid** files were added so new shape was generated manually with `gdaltindex` command. When new shapefile is created I go to layer configuration in GeoServer and press "**Compute from data**" but BBox does not change (I know for sure it now has larger BBox). If I do a GeoServer **restart** and then press "Compute from data" for this layer only then BBox gets recalculated. That is an issue one.

Even when I successfully restart GeoServer and recalculate BBox issue two persists: when opening GWC GUI for layer caching I see that BBox still has the old values. To fix this I have to go to `../data/gwc-layers/LayerInfoImpl-xxxx` and manually change coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, known behavior, computing the bbox all the time in the reader would be too expensive, and there is no API to tell the reader that you want to undergo an expensive re-computation (most of the code assumes calling onto the bbox of a grid coverage reader is instant, so those calls are spread out a bit everywhere).

You'll have to "reset" the GeoServer configuration to make it recognize the new bbox.

Comment: By "reset" GeoServer configuration you mean http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/reset.html ?

Comment: Yes, either that or from the user interface (but I guess you're automating, so yeah, that :-p )

Comment: Nope, not automating:) In GUI Server status > Resource Cache > Clear?

Comment: Also about "drop all caches" sounds dangerous. Need to be sure that this action will never ever might trigger cached image data deletion.

Comment: It's talking about in memory caches there, like feature types structure and the like, not tiles.

Comment: Just need to be sure that there is no way that caches tiles might be deleted after doing a reset. Is the button to "reset" the GeoServer configuration found here: Server status > Resource Cache > Clear?.

Comment: I participated in writing some of that code and don't believe it's going to delete the tile caches, but I suggest you to try for yourself, if you want guarantees look for commercial support contracts.